# Date output in expected format between two dates

Tags: bash, rhel, date, text-formatting

I want date output in format like...

```
01/01/2020
02/01/2020
03/01/2020
04/01/2020
05/01/2020
06/01/2020
07/01/2020
08/01/2020
09/01/2020
10/01/2020
11/01/2020
12/01/2020
13/01/2020
14/01/2020
15/01/2020
16/01/2020
17/01/2020
18/01/2020
19/01/2020
20/01/2020
21/01/2020
22/01/2020
23/01/2020
24/01/2020
25/01/2020
26/01/2020
27/01/2020
28/01/2020
29/01/2020
30/01/2020
```

currently I am using ...

```
cal 01 2020 | grep -v "[A-Z][a-z]"| tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | awk '$1~/[0-9]/ { printf "%02s/%02s/%4s\n",$1,"01","2020"}'
```

I want format as above be for `01/01/2017` to `31/12/2019`.How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

timestamp=$( date -d '2017-01-01 12:00' +%s )

while [ "$thedate" != '31/12/2019' ]; do
        printf -v thedate '%(%d/%m/%Y)T' "$timestamp"
        timestamp=$(( timestamp + 86400 ))

        printf '%s\n' "$thedate"
done
```

The above script first uses GNU `date` to get the UNIX timestamp for noon on the start date (it will be `1483268400`).  It then iterates until the end date has been found and outputted. In each iteration, we increment `timestamp` with 86400 seconds (24 hours).

The date strings are produced with the built-in `printf` utility in `bash`, which is able to format a datetime string from a UNIX timestamp with its `%(...)T` format (this requires `bash` release 4.3 or later).  It also prints directly to the variable `thedate` with `-v`.

On some systems without GNU `date`, you would be able to get the start date's timestamp with the native `date` utility using another format of the command line arguments.  On OpenBSD, for example, it's done with

```
date -j +%s 201701011200
```

See `man date` on your particular Unix.

Some extended implementations of `awk` could also be use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print mktime("2017 01 01 12 00 00") }'
```

But if you have such an `awk` (GNU `awk` or `mawk`), then you might as well do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
        timestamp = mktime("2017 01 01 12 00 00")

        while (thedate != "31/12/2019") {
                thedate = strftime("%d/%m/%Y", timestamp)
                timestamp += 86400

                print thedate
        }
}'
```

Comment: Its giving error invalid format character line3 i am using rhel 5.9

Comment: @KalpeshBhoj Line 3? I wonder what statement that would be? If it's the `printf`, then you may have a slightly too old `bash`. You could also try the `awk` code that I just added.

Comment: awk works beautifuly.Thanks

Comment: @KalpeshBhoj I looked up RedHat 5.9, and it appears that it shipped with a fairly old release of `bash`, which is why the shell code doesn't quite work for you. Also note that that release of RedHat is quite old and that you may want to upgrade at some point soon.

Comment: FWIW using a `%F` date format for the date generation and calculations (or testing the timestamp in the loop instead of thedate) and then just shuffling the order of the fields for printing would let you do `thedate < "2019-12-31"` and so the code would then not go into an infinite loop if someone provided an invalid end date or a date that was before the start date.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to add a nested for-loop with first iteration for the year and the next - month. for each month, you would do what you've already done, printing the month and year in the end of the awk.

Comment: Can you expain for loop ?

Comment: If you want to cycle through a set of things. 

you can type it in shell:

`for i in {1..12}
>do
>   echo $i
>done`

This will print out the numbers from 1 to 12

All on one line: `for i in {1..12}; do echo $i; done

The other solution is better, as it requires less typing.